# Animate WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, animation

I have a windows form.
I would like, when a certain button is click to animate an expansion of the form, revealing new section of the form (without having to forms, and animating one of them).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a nice enough effect by relying on a `Timer`. Here you have a sample code showing how to "animate" the increasing size of the main form after clicking on a button. By increasing/decreasing all the variables (X/Y inc. values or interval) you can get full control on how the animation "looks". Just include a button (`button1`) and a timer (`timer1`) on your form and the code below.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int timerInterval, curWidth, curHeight, incWidth, incHeight, maxWidth, maxHeight;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            curWidth = this.Location.X + this.Width;
            curHeight = this.Location.Y + this.Height;
            incWidth = 100;
            incHeight = 20;
            maxWidth = 2000;
            maxHeight = 1500;
            timerInterval = 100;
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            timer1.Interval = timerInterval;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            curWidth = curWidth + incWidth;
            curHeight = curHeight + incHeight;
            if (curWidth >= maxWidth)
            {
                curWidth = maxWidth;
            }
            if (curHeight >= maxHeight)
            {
                curHeight = maxHeight;
            }

            this.Width = curWidth;
            this.Height = curHeight;

            if (this.Width == maxWidth && this.Height == maxHeight)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              timer1.Enabled = !timer1.Enabled;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the code in `button1_Click` can be more concise like this `timer1.Enabled = !timer1.Enabled;`

Comment: @KingKing good point, I have updated the code. Honestly, I didn't know that the Timer can be triggered through the Enabled property; I thought that it was a boolean variable indicating just the state.